# PostgreSQL insert query

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I try to insert a single line to log table, but it throws an error message . ><

The `log` table structure is like this:

```
no         integer  NOT NULL nextval('log_no_seq'::regclass)    
ip         character varying(50)    
country    character varying(10)    
region     character varying(10)    
city       character varying(50)    
postalCode character varying(10)    
taken      numeric  
date       date
```

and my query:

```
INSERT INTO log (ip,country,region,city,postalCode,taken,date) VALUES 
("24.24.24.24","US","NY","Binghamton","11111",1,"2011-11-09")
```

`=> ERROR:  column "postalcode" of relation "log" does not exist`

second try query :  (without postalcode)

```
INSERT INTO log (ip,country,region,city,taken,date) VALUES 
("24.24.24.24","US","NY","11111",1,"2011-11-09")
```

`=> ERROR:  column "24.24.24.24" does not exist`

I don't know what I did wrong...

And PostgreSQL does not have datetime type? (2011-11-09 11:00:10)

Comment: PostgreSQL has as datetime type, it calls it [timestamp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html). Also, the product is PostgreSQL, not Postgre. If you were going to shorten it, it'd be Postgres (that's actually the name it had before gaining SQL support).

Comment: Double quotes are for quote identifiers (such as table and column names), single quotes are for string literals.

Comment: What happens is that people learn on MySQL, where timestamp was originally defined as auto-updating with the latest timestamp if it was the first timestamp column.  After realizing they'd used a SQL reserved keyword and type for something other than what it was designated to do, MySQL, stuck with keeping backward compatibility, needed a timestamp type field that didn't autoupdate, so they invented datetime as a type.  The SQL spec defines the Timestamp and timestamp with timezone types.  Datetime is MySQL's creation.  Wish they'd have at least reversed the meanings way back when...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try single quotes (e.g. '2011-11-09')

Comment: Also: don't use MixedCase. Someday it will bite back at you. Also: date is a reserved word (typename) don't use it, even if it appears to work.

Comment: Yep that's sound advice. The postalCode error is probably already mixed-case-ass-biting.

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL has a "datetime" type: `timestamp`. Read the [manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html).

The double-qutes `""` are used for identifiers if you want them *as is*. It's best you never have to use them as @wildplasser advised.

String literals are enclosed in single quotes `''`.

Start by reading the chapter [Lexical Structure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html). It is very informative. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try it rewrite in this way:

INSERT INTO log (ip,country,region,city,"postalCode",taken,date) VALUES 
('24.24.24.24','US','NY','Binghamton','11111',1,'2011-11-09');

When you are using mixed case in the name of column, or reserved words (such as "column", "row" etc.), you have to use double quotes, instead of values, where you have to use a single ones, as you can see in the example.